How to find mean and median of frequency table using python
I am new to python data analysis and I am working on census data, here is an example of the data,

| geo_area   |Total | 2-5km|5-10km|
|------------|------| ----| -----|
| E02000001  | 5378 | 385 | 241|
| E02000002  | 3238 | 474 |394 |
| E02000003  | 5238 | 603 | 541|
| E02000004  | 3113 | 354 |277 | 
| E02000005  | 4862 | 684 | 532|
| E02000006  | 4271 | 676 |408 |  

Where the first column is the geographical area, the second column is total distance travelled to work and the remaining columns are distances between 2-5km and 5-10 km. I excluded the other columns (10-20 km, 20-30 km, 30-40 km, 40-60 km, over 60 km and finally 0 km (working from home)) because it was too long. Also I've shown only 6 rows but the data is over 7000 rows.
The values of columns 2-5 km and 5-10km are frequencies.
I would like to determine both the average and median distances travelled for each geographical area?
I am not too sure if this is correct, but for the median, I wrote the following definition:
def median_calculator(df):
    full_list_of_numbers = []
    for col in df.columns:
        full_list_of_numbers.append(((df[col].cumsum() - (df[col].sum(axis=0)/2).T) < 0).sum())
    return full_list_of_numbers

I am struggling with the mean calculation and don't even know if the median above is a correct application. Also, can I use df.groupby('geographical_areas').agg({mean_distance: 'mean, 'median_distance:'median}) or is that incorrect?
Here is a link to the data if anyone is interested:
It is the file census2021-ts058-msoa in the zip file (TS058    Distance travelled to work under Work and Travel.
I appreciate the help, really.

pandas of course has mean, median and all typical stats functions already implemented...

How does that work on frequency data. Would you be able to provide an example please given the data above so I can see what your saying?

Do you expect, that we type your table data by hand? Please don't share text data as a picture.

Oh sorry, struggled with adding a table, as it kept going into a series so I inserted as code.  Will keep that in mind next time :).

Using the dataset you provided, you only need to use some indexing to get the answer you are looking for.
# Getting the data set
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request as urllib2
import pandas as pd

r = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/output/census/2021/census2021-ts058.zip").read()
file = ZipFile(BytesIO(r))
distance_to_work = file.open("census2021-ts058-msoa.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(distance_to_work)

# Getting mean and median (selecting all rows from column 3 and out)
mean = df.iloc[:,3:].mean()
median = df.iloc[:,3:].median()

Grouping the areas
Grouping the dataset without doing anything with it first will not work. I assume you meant grouping by district, and in the data set the districts have an associated count in the string. First, you must remove this count, then you can generate a group object which you can query for mean and median.
# Grouping by geography

# removing useless columns
df = df.drop(columns=["geography code", "date"])

# Need to remove count in geography tag
df["geography"] = df["geography"].apply(
    lambda area: "".join([char for char in area if not char.isdigit()])
)

# create DataFrameGroupBy object
group = df.groupby("geography")


mean_by_district = group.mean()
median_by_district = group.median()

Getting mean distance travelled
Using the two concepts above we can build the following data frame:
# Sum the frequencies
df = group.sum()

# Select only useful data (selecting only km columns)
df = df.iloc[:,1:-2]
> df




geography
Distance travelled to work: Less than 2km
Distance travelled to work: 2km to less than 5km
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km
Distance travelled to work: 10km to less than 20km
Distance travelled to work: 20km to less than 30km
Distance travelled to work: 30km to less than 40km
Distance travelled to work: 40km to less than 60km
Distance travelled to work: 60km and over




Adur
3313
3395
3962
2520
751
529
224
343


Allerdale
5985
3410
3673
5772
4861
1672
1355
646


Amber Valley
6641
6678
8060
10545
2643
636
481
768


Arun
8934
7824
11074
8050
2806
1254
1230
1252


Ashfield
7136
9309
9681
7594
2454
786
493
785


Ashford
7210
9099
3842
5105
3928
1822
982
2079


Babergh
4413
2815
3658
5859
3074
1102
678
892


Barking and Dagenham
6479
11957
11182
16823
4676
1054
595
1031



Now, from here you need to make a choice. We can assume the average distance is the midpoint between values in the column names, but for more the 60km it could be anything.
Using that you can simply multiply the columns by the chosen scalar.
df_in_km = df * [1, 2.5, 7.5, 15, 25, 35, 50, 70]

This gives us:



geography
Distance travelled to work: Less than 2km
Distance travelled to work: 2km to less than 5km
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km
Distance travelled to work: 10km to less than 20km
Distance travelled to work: 20km to less than 30km
Distance travelled to work: 30km to less than 40km
Distance travelled to work: 40km to less than 60km
Distance travelled to work: 60km and over




Adur
3313.0
8487.5
29715.0
37800.0
18775.0
18515.0
11200.0
24010.0


Allerdale
5985.0
8525.0
27547.5
86580.0
121525.0
58520.0
67750.0
45220.0


Amber Valley
6641.0
16695.0
60450.0
158175.0
66075.0
22260.0
24050.0
53760.0


Arun
8934.0
19560.0
83055.0
120750.0
70150.0
43890.0
61500.0
87640.0


Ashfield
7136.0
23272.5
72607.5
113910.0
61350.0
27510.0
24650.0
54950.0


Ashford
7210.0
22747.5
28815.0
76575.0
98200.0
63770.0
49100.0
145530.0


Babergh
4413.0
7037.5
27435.0
87885.0
76850.0
38570.0
33900.0
62440.0


Barking and Dagenham
6479.0
29892.5
83865.0
252345.0
116900.0
36890.0
29750.0
72170.0



Getting median and mean distance travelled in each district
Now we have km travelled in each bracket in the df_in_km data frame and frequency in the df data frame.
mean_distance_by_district = df_in_km.sum(axis=1)/df.sum(axis=1)

The median of individuals
Here we need to do something in the line of the function you have in your question.
Using the data frame grouped by district and summed, we can get the total people in the survey by using .sum(axis=1). Using the cumsum(axis=1) as you did will guide us to the correct bracket of people in the median.
(df.cumsum(axis=1).T - df.sum(axis=1)/2).T > 0




geography
Distance travelled to work: Less than 2km
Distance travelled to work: 2km to less than 5km
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km
Distance travelled to work: 10km to less than 20km
Distance travelled to work: 20km to less than 30km
Distance travelled to work: 30km to less than 40km
Distance travelled to work: 40km to less than 60km
Distance travelled to work: 60km and over




Adur
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true


Allerdale
false
false
false
true
true
true
true
true


Amber Valley
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true


Arun
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true


Ashfield
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true


Ashford
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true


Babergh
false
false
false
true
true
true
true
true


Barking and Dagenham
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true



The first true value is the bracket that is in the median of the district.
median_df_mask = (df.cumsum(axis=1).T - df.sum(axis=1)/2).T > 0
median_by_individual = median_df_mask.apply(
  lambda row: [key for key, value in row.items() if value][0], 
  axis=1
)




geography
0




Adur
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km


Allerdale
Distance travelled to work: 10km to less than 20km


Amber Valley
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km


Arun
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km


Ashfield
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km


Ashford
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km


Babergh
Distance travelled to work: 10km to less than 20km


Barking and Dagenham
Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km



If you want it in numeric values you can use a mapper as such:
conversions = [1, 2.5, 7.5, 15, 25, 35, 50, 70]
mapper = {c: conversions[i] for i, c in enumerate(df.columns)}
numeric_median = median_by_individual.apply(lambda x: mapper[x])




geography
0




Adur
7.5


Allerdale
15.0


Amber Valley
7.5


Arun
7.5


Ashfield
7.5


Ashford
7.5


Babergh
15.0


Barking and Dagenham
7.5




Thank you so much for your response. Regarding the first, getting the mean and median using .iloc(), how does that work if the third column is total distance travelled? Column 4 and onwards are at set kilometers. What I mean is that the .loc().mean() or iloc().median() is it performing the analysis in mind of the total or it doesn't really matter because it does it anyway. Sorry if I am confusing it, it's only that the data is a frequency data and I wasn't too sure if .loc().mean() or iloc().median() was able to that without building a function. Sorry if I am confusing things :).

I think there are some misunderstandings of the data set. The data set contains the number of people who traveled in the ranges less than 2km, 2-5km, and so on. This means that Column 3 Total is just the total of people who responded to the survey in that district/row. When using the iloc or integer-location we are simply indexing the data we want. You can look at exactly what median does here. Without grouping by district you get the median across all 7500 rows, i.e. the entire data set.

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I will add how to get the actual distance in km.

Thank you again for the explanation. I didn't think it was that simple to do :). I really appreciate your help. Looking forward to see how you get actual distance in km.

Added some stuff now, let me know if I understood your problem statement.

I just wanted to clarify one thing, in my case geography code is relevant and not the district. As the codes will be mapped to a postcode sector. Nevertheless, the method you showed is still applicable but I would simply change the following,
removing useless columns
df = df.drop(columns=["geography code", "date"])
so I can keep geography code rather than geography. Is that correct?
Also, one last thing, can you clairfy your assumption "We can assume the average distance is the midpoint between values in the column names, but for more the 60km it could be anything".

You can certainly group on geo_code rather than geography! The assumption is to get a numerical value for the rows. An example being  Distance travelled to work: 5km to less than 10km would under the assumption become the midpoint between 5km and 10km, which is 7.5km. This is up to you of course. When there is no midpoint as with Distance travelled to work: 60km and over, it becomes harder since it could be 61km or 250km. I just chose 70km, but it is really up to you to interpret.
